# Creating a new WinForm each time pressing a button in a main WinForm

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I have WinForm C# application that every time you press on the green button:
[image]

It opens a new WinForm window. This is the code after pressing the green button:

```
private void toolStripButtonFilter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ColumnFilter columnFilter = new ColumnFilter(listView1);
    columnFilter.FilterOKUpdate += new FilterOKEventHandler(ColumnFilter_OKFilter);
    columnFilter.ShowDialog();
}
```

When you close the `ColumnFilter` window, I use `this.Close();`.
Is it make sense to create a new form every time someone press the button?
Or maybe there it is better to initialize the `ColumnFilter` WinForm only one time in the main form?

Comment: Is your `ColumnFilter` initialization expensive from time or from resource computation perspective? If your answer is no then your approach is fine.

Comment: No, it only creates the GUI.

Comment: In that case I think it's okay. But if you share with us the code of `ColumnFilter` window then we can make sure that it is not costy.

Answer (score 1):

For the first time if someone clicks that green button, you can create the form, and then when they choose to close it, you should hide it instead of closing it. So second time if they choose to open it you should show it.

Simple commands:

`this.Hide();`

`this.Show();`

Comment: It sounds good but what is the difference if I am closing the window with `this.Close()` and when you click to open new window it again calls `ShowDialog()`?